# Nombres de archivos con caracteres extraños

Tags: java, eclipse, java-8

Estoy intentando sacar un listado de los archivos en un directorio, con este código:

```
public static void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
        for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
            if (!fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
            } 
        }
    }
```

El listado lo hace bien, excepto que los caracteres especiales (letras con acentos, '¿', '¡', 'ñ') los muestra incorrectamente. Supongo que debe ser algo referente al charset, o al encoding (aún no me queda clara la diferencia) pero no consigo encontrar la solución.

Por ejempolo, el archivo

> Perdón, perdón.txt

Lo toma como

> Perd�n, Perd�n.txt

Gracias por su apoyo.

¡Saludos!

Comment: ¿En qué consola, dónde o cómo estás corriendo tu programa? ¿IntelliJ, Eclipse, Netbeans, la cmd de windows directamente con el comando java?

Comment: La consola de eclipse. En la consola de windows se muestran correctamente los nombres

Comment: Checa Windows> Preference> General> Workspace > Text file Encoding > Utf-8> Apply and Close

Comment: Prueba también Run > Run Configuration > Common > Encoding > Utf-8 > Run

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios, @JaimeMenéndez, revisé la configuración y está así como comentas. La cambié a ISO-8859-1 y los muestra correctamente... ya no entiendo...